# Бесконечная прокрутка таблицы с учетом colspan/rowspan

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, olap

Как можно реализовать бесконечную прокрутку таблицы с учетом объединенных ячеек?

Необходимо реализовать pivotgrid с большим количеством обрабатываемых данных. Сложность заключается в отрисовке заголовков таблицы, так как рисовать необходимо не все заголовки, а только видимые их части (+ запас на прокрутку).

Возможные решения:

1. Без плавности прокрутки, дискретно, перерисовывать всю таблицу заголовка. (все таки, хотелось бы плавности)
2. Реализовать таблицу на div'ах и организовать достраивание и удаление скрывшихся элементов при прокрутке. (не удалось найти пример такой динамической таблицы с учетом объединения ячеек)
3. Реализовать таблицу-заголовок из последовательности таблиц, которые достраивать и удалять по мере необходимости [Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/madreason/0cjcpcr3/1/). (сложность реализации переходов между таблицами, ячейки не должны разъединяться, метка должна быть общей)
4. Стоит посмотреть в сторону flexbox...

Буду благодарен за любой совет.

Comment: первое о чем стоит подумать, так это о том, что будет, когда одна строка больше передаваемого блока (скажем передаем так)
`[500x1,1x1,1x1],[null,1x1,1x1]` итд, точно ли вам придет 500 1x1 ? Т.е. есди у вас блоки всегда начинаются общим разделителем а высота ячеек одинаковая, то пролемы нет. Если же у вас никогда не наступает общий делитель, то проблема есть с рендерингом, вм нужно пререндерить все правые блоки, прежде чем доскролить до них.

Comment: Высота и количество ячеек заканчивающегося блока всегда будет совпадать с высотой и количеством начинающегося блока. А ширина частного элемента в блоке вполне может быть шире всего блока, даже быть равной ширине всех блоков. В идеале хотелось бы просто матрицу div'ов ( видимая часть с запасом), в которых при скроллинге прокручивать данные и задавать классы, с помощью которых они бы визуально объединялись в один элемент(склеивались с соседними)...@eicto

Comment: Как регулируется ширина таблицы?

Comment: @Сахарок Не понял вопроса. Размеры задаем снаружи, при изменении размеров элемента в который рендерим, оповещаем об этом контроллер, он перерисовывает таблицу.

Comment: @madreason в примере на JSFiddle есть ячейка которая colspan'ит несколько столбцов. Каким образом регулируется размер таблицы, если такая ячейка никак не вмещается в текущий размер? Собственно проблема заголовков аналогично. Плюс ширины столбцов могут быть разными - каким образом должна вести себя таблица в такой ситуации?

Comment: @Сахарок Для меня эта проблема уже не актуальна, задачу решил. Подводных камней много, чтобы все объяснить нужно писать цикл статей)